# copy data from column 1 in table 1 to column 2 in table 2 and ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a table 1 in wordpress as

```
wp_term_relationships (
   object_id bigint(20),
   term_taxonomy_id bigint(20),
   term_order int(11)
)
```

and table 2 as

```
 wp_test (
    object_id bigint(20),
    term_taxonomy_id bigint(20)
)
```

Now I am trying to update `wp_term_relationships` with the values in `wp_test` as

```
update ignore wp_term_relationships m1 
inner join wp_test m2
on (m1.term_taxonomy_id = m2.term_taxonomy_id)
set m1.object_id = m2.object_id
```

However, all the values of `wp_test` do not get updated to `wp_term_relationships`

I have even tried straight up inserting the values from `wp_test` into `wp_test_relationships`

by using an insert as

```
insert ignore into wp_term_relationships(object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
select object_id, term_taxonomy_id from wp_test
```

But it just updates the `term_taxonomy_id` values with the corresponding `object_id` values  as 0  or
`object_id` values with the corresponding `term_taxonomy_id` values as 0

How can I transfer these 2 columns from `wp_test` into `wp_term_relationships`

Comment: To make it simpler, I am looking for a query that will enable me to transfer contents of column1, column2 from table 1 into the corresponding columns in table 2 with duplicate handling ofcourse.   I assume putting "update ignore" or "insert ignore" should take care of that?

Comment: saying "duplicate handling" is ambiguous; what should happen for duplicates? Should there *be* duplicates, or should the new value take the place of the old, or should the new value be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is an `INSERT` **without** `IGNORE` and **with** `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead:

```
INSERT INTO 
  wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
SELECT 
  object_id, 
  term_taxonomy_id 
  FROM wp_test
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = VALUES(term_taxonomy_id)
```

Note that this assumes that you have a unique constraint on wp_term_relationships.object_id

## edit for different case:

If you mean that what constitutes a "duplicate" is a distinct combination of the two columns, then you need to add a unique constraint on the two columns in MySQL, and then use your `INSERT IGNORE` query:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_term_relationships ADD UNIQUE (object_id, term_taxonomy_id);
```

Comment: Well then, I must ask about the ambiguous nature of your request... What constitutes a 'duplicate' in your requirement? perhaps there can be duplicates in either column, but no duplicate rows of both distinct values? i.e. no common pairs?

Comment: Yes, you got it. There can be duplicate values in both columns but no duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships m1, wp_test m2
SET m1.term_taxonomy_id = m2.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE m1.object_id = m2.object_id;
```

I am assuming that tables are linked by a column called "object_id".

Comment: That will give a duplicate key error. If you see the previous answer comments, the 2 columns have duplicates, however a row has to be unique.